# SQLAlchemy relationships to same table

Tags: python, sqlite, orm, sqlalchemy

I have declared following models:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Table,
    Integer,
    Date,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///data.sqlite')
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


lineup = Table('lineups', Base.metadata,
               Column('match_id', Integer, ForeignKey('data.id')),
               Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('players.id')))


class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date)
    tournament = Column(String)
    team1 = Column(String)
    team2 = Column(String)
    team1_lineup = relationship('Player', secondary=lineup)
    team2_lineup = relationship('Player', secondary=lineup)
    best_of = Column(Integer)
    maps = relationship('Map')
    score = Column(String)


class Map(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'maps'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    match = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('data.id'))
    name = Column(String)
    score = Column(String)


class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'players'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = Column(String)
    team = Column(String)
```

And I'm creating new `Match` object this way:

```
match = Match(...) # all kwargs except team1_lineup and team2_lineup

p1 = Player(id=1, nickname='p1', team='team')
p2 = Player(id=2, nickname='p2', team='team')
p3 = Player(id=3, nickname='p2', team='team')

match.team1_lineup.append(p1)
match.team2_lineup.append(p2)
match.team2_lineup.append(p3)
```

After commiting new object, I'm querying it.

```
>>> from hltv.models import Match, DBSession
>>> s = DBSession()
>>> m = s.query(Match).first()
>>> m.team1_lineup
[<hltv.models.Player object at 0x7f1a93009d10>, <hltv.models.Player object at 0x7f1a93009d90>, <hltv.models.Player object at 0x7f1a93009e10>]
>>> m.team2_lineup
[<hltv.models.Player object at 0x7f1a93009d10>, <hltv.models.Player object at 0x7f1a93009d90>, <hltv.models.Player object at 0x7f1a93009e10>]
```

The problem is `m.team1_lineup` and `m.team2_lineup` are the same. How can I solve this?
Additionally, how do I assign ID to every lineup (lineups with same players should have same ID)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem. I had to add IDs to lineup (which I've renamed to Team) and specify how to join tables by providing two different IDs for those teams. Another way way solution posted by André.

Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Table,
    Integer,
    Date,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///data.sqlite')
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date)
    tournament = Column(String)
    best_of = Column(Integer)
    score = Column(String)
    maps = relationship('Map')
    team1_id = Column(ForeignKey('team.id'))
    team2_id = Column(ForeignKey('team.id'))

    team1 = relationship('Team', primaryjoin='Match.team1_id == Team.id')
    team2 = relationship('Team', primaryjoin='Match.team2_id == Team.id')


class Map(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'map'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    match = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('data.id'))
    name = Column(String)
    score = Column(String)


lineup = Table('lineup',
               Base.metadata,
               Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id')),
               Column('team_id', Integer, ForeignKey('team.id')))



class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = Column(String)


class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'team'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    players = relationship('Player', secondary=lineup, backref='teams')
```

Comment: I am glad to help in a final solution. Dont forget do set your own answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions in relationships:

- Considering that you have for each match 2(two) teams and 2(two) differents line up, when you use that same match id for two different lineups happens this query mistake to return the lineups;
- I am not good in sports, but I think that you can do a better normalization on models. For example: Create a new model Team

My suggestion is change some models for **Many to many**, like that:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Table,
    Integer,
    Date,
    String,
    ForeignKey,
)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///data.sqlite')
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

lineup = Table('lineups', Base.metadata,
               Column('team_id', Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id')),
               Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('players.id')))

class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement= True)
    name = Column(String)
    team_lineup = relationship('Player',secondary=lineup)

match_team = Table('match_teams', Base.metadata,
               Column('match_id', Integer, ForeignKey('matches.id')),
               Column('team_id', Integer, ForeignKey('teams.id')))

class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'matches'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement= True)
    date = Column(Date)
    tournament = Column(String)
    team = relationship('Team',secondary=match_team)
    best_of = Column(Integer)
    maps = relationship('Map')
    score = Column(String)

class Map(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'maps'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement= True)
    match = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('matches.id'))
    name = Column(String)
    score = Column(String)

class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'players'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement= True)
    nickname = Column(String)
```

Creating objets...

```
s = DBSession()

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine) 
Base.metadata.create_all(engine) 

t1 = Team(name="t1")
t2 = Team(name="t2")

p1 = Player()
p2 = Player()
p3 = Player()

s.add(p1)
s.add(p2)
s.add(p3)

t1.team_lineup.append(p1)
t2.team_lineup.append(p2)
t2.team_lineup.append(p3)

s.add(t1)
s.add(t2)

m = Match()
m.tournament="xpto"
m.team.append(t1)
m.team.append(t2)

s.add(m)
s.commit()
```

And after that, you can see that the lineups is like your expectation:

```
>>> m = s.query(Match).first()
>>> for t in m.team:
...     print t.team_lineup
... 
[<__main__.Player object at 0x10b57c890>]
[<__main__.Player object at 0x10b57c910>, <__main__.Player object at 0x10b57c990>]
```

In this case you can have "n" teams for each match. I don't know if is possible in the sport that you are managing.